# Converting bytes to an escaped hexadecimal string

Tags: c++, strings, c++14, escaping

I wrote this function to convert an array of bytes to a C/C++ string representation using hexadecimal escape codes (`\xhh`). Any suggestions are welcome:

```
std::string toEscapedHexaString(const std::uint8_t * data, const int dataSizeBytes, 
                                const int maxCols = 80, const int padding = 0)
{
    assert(data != nullptr);
    assert((maxCols % 4) == 0);
    assert((padding % 2) == 0);

    int column = 0;
    char hexaStr[64] = {'\0'};

    std::string result = "\"";
    for (int i = 0; i < dataSizeBytes; ++i, ++data)
    {
        std::snprintf(hexaStr, sizeof(hexaStr), "\\x%02X", static_cast<unsigned>(*data));
        result += hexaStr;
        column += 4;

        if (column >= maxCols)
        {
            if (i != (dataSizeBytes - 1)) // If not the last iteration
            {
                result += "\"\n\"";
            }
            column = 0;
        }
    }

    // Add zero padding at the end to ensure the data size
    // is evenly divisible by the given padding value.
    if (padding > 0)
    {
        for (int i = dataSizeBytes; (i % padding) != 0; ++i)
        {
            result += "\\x00";
            column += 4;

            if (column >= maxCols)
            {
                if ((i + 1) % padding) // If not the last iteration
                {
                    result += "\"\n\"";
                }
                column = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    result += "\"";
    return result;
}
```

You can control the number of columns in the output, so for example, converting `Hello World!\0` with 20 columns max (not counting the quotes):

```
const unsigned char str[] = "Hello World!";
auto result = toEscapedHexaString(str, sizeof(str), 20);

/* result = 
   "\x48\x65\x6C\x6C\x6F"
   "\x20\x57\x6F\x72\x6C"
   "\x64\x21\x00"
*/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Use of assert

Some of the uses of `assert` here look semi-broken, at least to me. Part of the definition of `assert` is that when you compile with `NDEBUG` defined, `assert` becomes a nop. When it is enabled, a failed assertion immediately aborts the program. For testing inputs to a function, neither of those is generally desirable. For such purposes, I usually define an `assure` that always does its thing, and throws an exception when the test fails.

#### snprintf

At the very least, I'd try to wrap the ugliness of using `snprintf` up into a reasonably neat little function like `to_hex` that just converts a number into its hex representation:

```
std::string to_hex(int in) { 
    // snprintf ugliness here
    return std::string(buffer);
}
```

Alternatively, since you're converting inputs to strings, and accumulating those together into a buffer anyway, consider using an `std::ostringstream`.

#### Logic

In a few places, the logic seems...less than pleasing, at least to me. For example:

```
if (column >= maxCols)
```

You've previously tested that `maxCols % 4 == 0`, and (assuming things work correctly) each item you add should be 4 more characters, so you should *never* see a result that's actually greater than `maxCols`--only less than `maxCols`, then equal to `maxCols`, then back to 0. This is harmless, and if you might want to support a `maxCols` that was *not* a multiple of 4, then it might even make good sense--but as things stand right now, it seems like there's a degree of...uncertainty about the real intent.

#### Reorganization

Right now you have code to ensure the maximum line length sprinkled liberally throughout the rest of the code. I'd be tempted to define a type that takes that as its single responsibility: when you create it, specify a maximum length. When you add characters to it, it tracks the length of the current "line", and when the maximum is reached (or exceeded) it adds a delimiter, and starts over. With this, the rest of the code gets a lot simpler in a hurry, and each piece of code has a much simpler, clearer purpose.

Comment: Thanks Jerry, good points! I think you meant `to_string` instead? `stoi` is for the other way around, string => integer? Unfortunately `to_string` doesn't allow specifying a base, so I'm thinking the only other way to avoid `snprintf` is using a `stringstream`...

Comment: Oops-yes, stoi was the wrong one. But you're right-I'd forgotten to_string doesn't let you specify the base.